# Lighweight to-do app similiar to Nitro Tasks but with arbitrary cloud syncing

Tags: linux, project-management, desktop-client, markdown

Concerning my personal task management, I've been using [Nitro Tasks](http://nitrotasks.com/#) for a couple of years now on all my Ubuntu computers. While this app comes pretty close to my ideal to-do app regarding usability, user interface and feature set, there is that huge disadvantage of being able to sync with dropbox only (used to be ubuntu one, too). As I move away from dopbox, I am looking for a to-do application with the following attributes:

**must haves**

- must run on (Ubuntu) Linux
- lightweight, modern, distraction free user interface
- support multiple lists
- no-backend concept for data storage: data should be stored locally on the respective client, and in a future proof format such as markdown, json or plain text; The goal is to select any local folder for data storage such as a USB device or any cloud storage folder other than dropbox.
- stand-alone client application (no browser based app), but could well be an HTML5 / node.js app which runs in a native container

**nice to haves**

- markdown for task descriptions
- sub task creation
- drag & drop to move to-do items
- Kanban functionality

**Apps, I have already checked out which are not appropriate**

- Tasque
- Task Coach
- Getting Things Gnome
- quite a few browser based apps

What applications could you recommend?